# Why is my colour change transition delayed?

Tags: html, css

I am making a footer and I wanted it to be a dark grey by default, then lighten up when you hover over it and then have the individual link lighten up even more when you hover over one in the footer.

I made a JSFiddle to show what I mean with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/v1rxk09x/

You can see better in the JSFiddle, but I think I screwed up with my CSS somewhere:

```
div.footer {
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;

}

div.foottext {
    font-family: 'Queen of Camelot', sans-serif;
    color: #757575;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition:0.3s;
}

div.foottext:hover {
    color: #cccccc;
    transition:0.3s;
}

div.foottext a:link
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #inherit;
    transition:0.3s;
}


div.foottext a:visited
{
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.foottext a:hover
{
    color: #ffffff;
    transition:0.3s;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

It works, but the links changing colour is delayed and I'm not sure why, you can see when you hover over 'Navigation' that it all fades to a light grey perfectly, apart from the links, which transition a bit later.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is that your desired result? 
https://jsfiddle.net/v1rxk09x/1/   
removed transition of links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to specify the `transition` property for every state. Just how the properties should update. When decalaring a different transition on hover this might cause some unexpected beahviour. Remove all `transition` properties except the first:

https://jsfiddle.net/vhfd60dy/

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks a lot, I understand it much better now!

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not quite sure if this is what you needed, but here we go.

I changed your:

```
div.foottext:hover {
    color: #cccccc;
    transition:0.3s;
}
```

To:

```
div.foottext a:hover {
    color: #cccccc;
    transition:0.3s;
}
```

Then it will only apply to your `<a href="">` tags.

Here is a snippet:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

div.foottext {
 color: #757575;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 text-align: center;
 transition:0.3s;
}

div.foottext a:hover {
 color: #cccccc;
 transition:0.3s;
}

div.foottext a:link
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 transition:0.3s;
}


div.foottext a:visited
{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}

div.foottext a:hover
{
 color: #ffffff;
 transition:0.3s;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="foottext"><p>Navigation - <a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```